# What does :layout tag in respond_with do in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What does the code below's :layout do?

```
respond_with( @comment, :layout => !request.xhr? )
```

The code above is handling rendering of the different MIME type based on request data type (If my understanding is correct).
What is the `:layout` tag doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation for [ActionController::Responder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html)

> respond_with also allow you to pass options that are forwarded to the
>   underlying render call. Those options are only applied success
>   scenarios. For instance, you can do the following in the create method
>   above:

So what the `:layout => !request.xhr?` it will pass this option down to the rendering.  So if you had an HTML resource called as a regular request, it would use the standard layout, but an HTML request made as an `XmlHttpRequest` would not use a layout

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the format way. This perfectly works too:

```
respond_to :html; :json
respond_with(@product, :layout => "landingpage")
```